# Geometric intuition for pf in fppf-topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-topology, sites

I am trying to learn a bit about algebraic spaces and the various topologies on categories of schemes in general. And, as it seems to always be the case, I am struggling with understanding how exactly some algebraic condition, in this case being locally of finite presentation, translates into geometry.

One geometric aspect that certainly plays a role is Chevalley's theorem on constructible sets. But other than that, how should one think geometrically or topologically about fppf-coverings? An [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/195197/131868) to ['What is the purpose of the flat/fppf/fpqc topologies?'](https://mathoverflow.net/q/195165/131868) says

> The fppf topology is similar to the etale topology, but now allowing maps $Y\to X$ which are open.

I can see why this is true to a certain extent, but surely being flat and locally of finite presentation is more than being open?

So I guess what I am trying to find out is how should one think of fppf-coverings more accurately than flat and open coverings? Or, approaching the question from the 'opposite' direction, what would break if we tried to define a topology by defining coverings as collections of morphisms $\{f_i:U_i\to X\}_{i\in I}$ of schemes such that each $f_i$ is flat, (universally) open and such that $X=\bigcup f_i(T_i)$?

Comment: I guess that this description is more philosophical. In fact, the latest topology that you described is sometimes called the fpuo (faithfully flat + universally open) topology, which seems to be incomparable with the fpqc topology.

Comment: The condition about being f.p is always automatic classical geometric objects and it is a good technical assumption to have some control. For example for f.p.q.c site (and I guess for the topology you defined) there are set theoretical problems about sheafification and things like that.

Comment: Of course one of the main points is the faithfully flat decent which is true in fpqc topology. The fact that f.p flat maps are open is nice and useful, but decent is the main point of flat sites, fpqc and fppf have more covers than etale site so the decent is more powerful, but having more covers mean that it is harder to work with things like cohomology and sheafification,  the fppf is a compromise between power of and difficulties of having more covers.